# Passing delegate method and dynamically invoking arguments

Tags: c#, delegates

I've asked a similar question before but I'm just having a hard time wrapping my head around this...

I have a delegate...

```
delegate void assertDelegate(params object[] args);
```

and I have a method that invokes the delegate...

```
public void assert(assertDelegate assertMethod, params object[] args) {
        string expectedValue;
        string actualValue;
        // derive value of 'expectedValue' and 'actualValue' from 'args'
        assertMethod.DynamicInvoke(expectedValue, actualValue);
    }
```

my thought was that there has to be a way to pass the action and dynamically invoke the arguments for that action...

```
assert(Assert.AreEqual,new object[]{ HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Id, "footer"});
```

but I'm getting the error `Expected a method with 'void AreEqual(params object[])' signature`.

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding `DynamicInvoke`?

Comment: the error you geting because signature of Assert.AreEqual and assertDelegate not the same

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do more general? You can use reflection for dynamic invoke some method passed to function and push parameters

Comment: What is the signature of Assert.AreEqual?

Comment: About 20 variations of areEqual exsists

Comment: I might be missing something but I fail to see the added benefits of this method you're trying to create. Why can't you call `Assert.Whatever` instead of wrapping it in an obscure 'black box' which does nothing by itself ?

Comment: I guess @gabba was right, you define delegate with signature object[], but you Assert.AreEqual is (object, object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delegate void assertDelegate(params object[] args);
```

This delegate signature does not match any signature of `Assert.AreEqual`.
Use instead:

```
delegate void assertDelegate(string first, string second);
```

Or a `Func<string, string>`.

Comment: @gabba Indeed it wont. This is simply a suggestion in case OP uses only string-string methods. He/she is free to do whatever suits his needs.